# FS Quest Crashed

Tags: fallout-shelter, android

This is my 4th vault project in FS --the 1st on Android.

I was taking The Cat Burglar quest.
Everything seemed okay until the party arriving and I entered the quest mode --the game was into never-ending loading screen.
I then forced-quit the game and retried.
The next time I entered the game, the party is returning from the quest that I have never been into.

[image]

Quest list showing that the party is returning to vault.

[image]

After the party reached back to vault, the quest is no longer there --I suppose it is considered complete, as it should have been still enlisted to retry if it has not. CMIIW on this, though.

[image]

Yet, there is no pet of supposed-to-be-rescued cat in my inventory.

[image]

Played 3 previous vaults on 3 different iOS device, have never seen this situation.
Any insight?

[Update]
Yes, @Ben, the quest is completed and the cat is there --yet not in my inventory.

[image]

Comment: Did you check in the "completed" quests tab to see what he verdict was?

Comment: Yes, @Ben, the quest is completed and the cat is there --yet not in my inventory.